# Animation is not occurring fluently

Tags: css, animation

I want to make an animation, but it is not working fluently. It is  an infinite animation. I want to make this animation without stopping anywhere and without any delays

My code:

```css
.line{
   height: 3px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   animation:colorchange 5s ease infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange {
     0%{
       background-color:blue;
       width: 140px;
     }
     20%{
       background-color: #8e44ad;
       width: 160px;
     }
     40%{
      background-color:#1abc9c;
      width: 120px;
     }
     60%{
       background-color:#d35400;
       width: 160px;
     }
     60% {
       background-color:blue;
       width: 120px;
     }
     80% {
       background-color: #34495e;
       width: 160px;
     }
     100% {
       background-color: red;
       width: 120px;
     }
  }
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

I want to make this animation without any breaking points. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Please see [how to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You have 2 changes at 60%.